# How to put a proper jQuery selector under if condition so that it work for all the cases?

Tags: jquery

Using Jquery each function, i am parsing a div data called as `myordersdiv`

As parsing the `myordersdiv`, i am creating an array and storing data .

**The issue i am facing is that**

If the `myordersdiv` has got one elmenet under it then its working fine and the o/p is

```
[{"name":"Choclate"}]
```

But in case if the `myordersdiv` has got two elmenets under it , then the o/p is

`[{"name":"ChocolateVanila "}]`  (**Its mixing both of them** )

The fiddle for the first case is

http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/3/

The fiddle for the second case is

http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/5/

Right the jQuery selector is

```
$.each($('#myordersdiv > ul'), function(i, elem) {
        name = $(elem).find("label").text();
        if (name != 'undefined') {
            //Creating product array 
            products.push({
                'name': name
            });
        }
    });
```

Could anybody please help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:-

```
var name;
var products = [];
$('#myordersdiv > ul').find('ul').each(function(){
    name = $(this).find("label").text();
    if (name != 'undefined') {
        //Creating product array 
        products.push({
            'name': name
        });
    }
 });

 var orderjson = JSON.stringify(products);
 console.log(orderjson);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Your current selector is only grabbing the immediate `ul` child element of `#myordersdiv`, and this wraps all your list elements. Thus, in the `$.each` function, it would get all the labels' text and concatenate them. There's several ways to fix the selectors, including the following:

```
 $.each($('.prd-items-detials > ul'), function(i, elem) {
    name = $(elem).find("label").text();

 $.each($('#myordersdiv label'), function(i, elem) {
    name = $(elem).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var name;
var products = [];

     $.each($('#myordersdiv > ul'), function(i, elem) {
            $(elem).find("label").each(function(i, elem) {
            var name=$(this).text();
                if (name != 'undefined') {
                //Creating product array 
                products.push({
                    'name': name
                });
            }
            });
        });
        var orderjson = JSON.stringify(products);
        console.log(orderjson);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/7/)

OR

use map in jquery to get all label value in array

```
 var labelValue = $('#myordersdiv ul li label').map(function (i, elem) {
        return $(this).text();

    }).get();

console.log(labelValue);
```

Comment: Thanks , but I have several elements to push to the json , not only the name  , for demo purpose i have shown that . 

      name = $(elem).find("label").text();
      image = $(elem).find('img').attr('src');
      quantity = parseInt($(elem).find("i.qt").text());
      price = $(elem).find("div.total").text();
      toppings = [];

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var name;
var products = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    name = $(this).parent('form').find("label").text();
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        products.push({
            'name': name
        });
    } else {
        var index = products.indexOf(name);
        products.splice(index, 1);
    }
    var orderjson = JSON.stringify(products);
    console.log(orderjson);
});
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GStDU/9/